# Get the Variable name inside the function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var temp = Testing(A, B, C, D);
```

In the above case I need inside the function parameters list. (i.e., A,B,C,D) in array list. (i.e., `arr[0]=A`, `arr[1]=B` etc.,).

Thanks & Advance....

Comment: It is not reliable to check on variable name instead of their value.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I really don't know what you mean please expand you question if you need help.

Comment: Please provide more code and describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: var temp=Testing(A,B,C,D); I need var result=A,B,C,D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding from question, you want to say how to pass array as parameter in function. So probably you can do it like

```
var A=['a','v','c','d'];
var a = function(Arr)
{
   for(var i=0;i<Arr.length;i++)
   {
     console.log("element",Arr[i]);
   };
};
a(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `arguments` object is a local variable available within all functions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

```js
var Testing = function() {
  alert(arguments[0]);
}

var temp = Testing(1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: You are a brave man, providing solution the question that was barely asked. ;)